# Using output from "with as" few times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I can't use t from

```
with t as (
        select row_number() OVER (partition by ID ORDER BY id) as numb, * 
        from my_table
        where id= 6
    )

select top 2 from t # it works
select top 2 from t # here I get error Invalid object name 't'.
```

Is there any tip to use t more than on time?

Comment: I just learned something new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this.  CTEs can only be used in one statement (though you can use it multiple times within one statement.

Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163346.aspx).  Snippit:

> Once a CTE is defined, it can be
>   referenced multiple times by the first
>   query that follows it.

And from [their documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

> A common table expression (CTE) can be
>   thought of as a temporary result set
>   that is defined within the execution
>   scope of a single SELECT, INSERT,
>   UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW
>   statement.

Emphasis on, "scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement."

Comment: +1: A WITH statement, AKA inline view/derived table, is unnecessary for the intended use -- a view.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any tip to use t more than on time?

Sure, if you are doing this in a stored proc, just dump it into a #temp table.  At the end of the stored proc, the #temp table disappears.

```
with t as (
        select row_number() OVER (partition by ID ORDER BY id) as numb, * 
        from my_table
        where id= 6
    )
select * into #tmp from t

select top 2 from #tmp -- good
select top 2 from #tmp -- good also
```

Outside of SP, just make sure you drop the #table before you attempt to create it again, otherwise the next `select ..into #name` will error out with `#name already exists`

Comment: Could probably do without the CTE in the first place with this method.

Comment: @Abe This is a general answer to "output from WITH several times". The CTE could involve recursive components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE only in a single query that follows the CTE. You can however make the query that follows as complicated as you wish.

In your example, you might consider a union between the 2 selects depending on precisely what you want. The code you gave isn't descriptive enough for me to suggest any other variants.